# How to keep the background image form and the labels be transparent over it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a background image on my form . I want to have a transparent label background over the form .

How can I do it?

Here is a picture of what I want if I was misunderstood. :)[image]

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I don't think the standard labels can do this by default, you best chance is to override paint functions of the control i guess.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg in fact that is just ***transparent to parent***, so it's in fact supported in `winforms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set this property in your form load event

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
```